# How can I make a variable static in Js?

Tags: javascript, variables, static

I want the newid to be incremented when I call the function.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Why not pass the newId to the method? Or have a global object in your workspace?

Comment: You can do this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/g8hqdkyx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make the function *close over* the variable, by declaring the variable in the surrounding context:

```
let newid = 3;
const generateTemplate = contact => {
    // ...
    newid++;
};
```